# Requested Android permissions not showing in app permission settings

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions

I'm working on a Cordova app that needs the permissions `INTERNET`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, and `CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE`. I have requested these permissions in the manifest like so

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

`INTERNET`, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, and `CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE` are considered normal permissions and according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal-dangerous) they will be automatically accepted by Android at install time and the user can't revoke them.

Now in the `MainActivity` created by Cordova I added this code within an `if` block that checks to make sure we are on 6.0 or above:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "has permission");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "no permission");
            requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
```

The problem is that on an Android device running 5.1.1 this works and I see all 4 permissions when I go to the permission settings of the app. However on a device running 7.0 and 7.1.1 I get a dialog asking to approve the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and all other permissions, since they are normal, do not get asked for approval. They are automatically approved. The issue is that even though I have permission, on the newer devices I can't do things related to these permissions and if I go to the app settings for permissions all I see is permission Storage granted. Nothing for `INTERNET`, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, or `CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE`. I have not tested specifically on a 6.0 device but I think I would have the same issue.

Why are the permissions not showing in the permission settings, and why cant I perform operations that need these permissions, even though Android says I have permission?

Comment: And what operations you are trying to do?

Comment: The app uses a Bonjour like service to automatically detect a device on the wifi network. On the older device it detects the device just fine. Newer devices dont see it. It sends the command to search but never finds anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal-dangerous) you linked to contains the following statement:

"The system doesn't prompt the user to grant normal permissions, and users cannot revoke these permissions. "

So all permissions except for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will always be granted. The only permission you have to ask for is the one which can be revoked.

> Why are the permissions not showing in the permission settings

Well, depending on the android version they may be a little hard to find. For example on my emulator running android 7.0, I found a list of all the permissions under Apps -> MyApp -> Permissions, and then clicking "All permissions" in the overflow menu.

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that the 3 will always be granted, however I still can't perform the functions I need to with these permissions even though they are granted. So I went to check the permission settings and I noticed on the newer devices the only permission showing in the list is the storage permission. I am using a Bonjour like service to detect another device on a network. On older devices the app works and will detect the device, but on newer devices it doesn't. It just sits and listens but never finds it.

Comment: I did not know about "All  Permissions". I tried it and sure enough the permissions are there.

Comment: @Jason Crosby - OK, so you can at least make sure that it's not a case of missing permissions. I'm wondering if the problem is due to some dependencies on older libraries (which try to do something and fail silently) but I'm afraid I can't help you there.